# Novel featuring a domed city

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm trying to identify a novel I borrowed years ago from the public library. Unfortunately, I had to return the book before I finished it.

The story involved a domed city in a post-apocalyptic world. The main character was employed as a engineer/repairman.

Life under the dome was pretty sweet for those who lived there, although the regime was very authoritarian. People had electronic valets which corresponded with your place in society. the valets of the rich were quite powerful, but the valets of the working class were weak.

There were refugees who lived outside the dome in the ruins of the former society. Among these refugees was a covert organization that opposed the authorities of the domed city.

Comment: It sounds similar to *Logan's Run*  MOVIE -  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logan%27s_Run_(film) - BOOK -https://www.amazon.co.uk/Logans-Run-William-F-Nolan/dp/0552084786/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1549041945&sr=1-3&keywords=logans+run+book

Comment: "Years ago" is approximately how many years?  5? 40?  Was it a new book?  Do you remember any details of the cover?  You should review the other [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) and see if there are additional details you can [edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/204504/edit) into your question.

Comment: Some parts of this remind me of McCarthy's *Queendom of Sol* books. There's mention in the fourth, *To Crush the Moon* to robotic Valets, noted to be tough enough to use as soldiers, a domed city is featured in the third book, and the structure of the eponymous "Queendom" is a monarchy across the stars, powered by Collapsium, black hole material.

Comment: It was approximately 8 or 9 years ago. Yes, it has some elements similar to Logan's Run, but it was a different story. As I recall, it seemed more like a James Blish type of novel than any other author I can name. The electronic valets were a prominent feature. I am not familiar with McCarthy's work, so I will have to investigate.